# Closed form of a series similar to exponential

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, wolfram-alpha

I do not know if the question has already been posted. I was trying to find a closed form for the sum

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^x}{n!}
$$

Is there a special function to think about (polylogarithm...)? Wolfram Alpha suggests that for some values of $x$ the answer is a multiple of $e$.

Thank you

Comment: [Dobiński's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula).

Comment: Oh, cool! Thank you all for the references